# How to stabilize an antenna

Tags: antenna-construction, vertical-antenna

I have an antenna on a building. It is made of steel and is about 10ft long. It wobbles a bit in high winds.

It is not going to do a Tacoma Narrows but it is a bit annoying.  Can I tie stainless steel marine wire to the top of the mast then weld a couple of steel tubes (2 feet) at the 5ft mark to hold the wire out 2ft (*this is all the space I have above the roof and then tie these below the antenna support*)

The antenna is supported on the wall in two places with a 2ft section of the same pipe.

Comment: It might also be good to run your plan by either the "Amateur Radio" StackExchange site, or the Amateur Radio subreddit to make sure whatever structural solution you use doesn't adversely affect the antenna reception.

Comment: "*tecoma naorrows*" ?

Comment: Tacoma Narrows suspension bridge, AKA Galloping Gertie.

Comment: [Tacoma Narrows Bridge collapse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XggxeuFDaDU).

Comment: Please tell us more about the antenna. Is it a UHF yagi TV antenna on a mast, or a fibreglass collinear, or a straight metal pole like a CB or HF vertical? Where does the coax cable connect? This matters because some antennas are more affected by metal than others.

Comment: Is the problem an aesthetic one or is the performance or physical integrity of the antenna being affected?

Comment: Hello Trevor, there isn't enough information for us to help you. Kindly edit the question to add more details. A photo is worth a thousand words, as they say.